# Streamlit Browser App does not open from Sagemaker Terminal

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker, streamlit

I am working on building a movie recommendation engine on aws sagemaker environment and i plan to show working demonstration for the same. I am trying to use the streamlit library for running the app.

After running the command: streamlit run app.py, it provides me 2 urls i.e. Network and External urls.

The issues is none of the url works. It results in connection timed out, the server does not respond.

Please help

Comment: Any solution to this issue @ronak? Mine doesn't render anything as well. Plus, how did you debug the issue? It doesn't return any logs as well :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following url `https://{NOTEBOOK_URL}/proxy/8501/`. You may have to change the proxy based on which proxy is used in the Network and External urls

Comment: https://{NB_URL}/proxy/8501/  Doesnt render the content. It says Please wait.... connecting

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps and it worked for me:

```
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate JupyterSystemEnv
pip uninstall --yes nbserverproxy
pip install --upgrade jupyter-server-proxy
sudo systemctl restart jupyter-server
```

The last command you write will close your terminal in Sagemaker, so you'll have to open up a new terminal window and run the following commands:

```
source activate pytorch_p39
pip install streamlit==1.11.0
```

Versions greater than 1.11.0 of streamlit don't seem to work unfortunately. This seems to be a problem with the jupyter-server-proxy library.

If your run:

```
streamlit hello --browser.serverAddress=0.0.0.0
```

The app should be here `https://{NOTEBOOK_URL}/proxy/8501/`