# Amazon SageMaker : streamlit hello => hello? No page loading

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, streamlit

I'm new to AWS. I'd like to host a streamlit app on SageMaker/EC2.
I've created a Notebook instance (linked to GitHub).
From the Notebook instance I open Jupyer Lab and then a terminal.
I successfully installed streamlit framework:

```
sh-4.2$ streamlit version
Streamlit, version 1.21.0
```

And when I want to execute a demo with `streamlit hello`, I get two URLs:

```
  Welcome to Streamlit. Check out our demo in your browser.
  Network URL: http://x.x.x.x:8501
  External URL: http://x.x.x.x:8501
```

However after opening them with a browser, no content displays and I finally get the "website is not accessible" message.

- I have tried downgrading streamlit version as proposed here (but it doesn't help): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63427965/streamlit-browser-app-does-not-open-from-sagemaker-terminal/75226979#75226979](https://stackoverflow.com)
- I have set firewall rules as follow: [image]
- I have tried another port: `streamlit hello --server.port 8888`

So far, nothing works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. trying to run from a notebook instance in sagemaker

Answer (score 0):

`streamlit hello --server.port 8888`
This runs your streamlit app on your localhost (basically your local machine serves as a server backend for your web app). Since you're using Sagemaker which itself is a server based JupyterLab IDE, the web app will be running on the localhost of the server you're assigned when you've created your Sagemaker instance.
In short, you can't test out your APIs or Web Apps working on a server based IDE.
The only possible way I've figured out is publicly hosting a specific port of my localhost server using [Ngrok][1]. Follow these steps -

1. Create account on Ngrok and get your AuthToken. (No need to take any paid subscription or give CC details). Complete command along with AuthToken will be visible on your dashboard once you login. It'll look like this - `ngrok config add-authtoken 2OOuo95syDj####$$#$#%^$^%$#$%$^$^%$^^#$%^^Qs` (copy it)
2. Go to any Jupyter Notebook and install Python Wrapper for Ngrok using `! pip install pyngrok`. You can do the same with conda env using `! conda install -c conda-forge pyngrok`.
3. In a new code cell import ngrok from pyngrok using `from pyngrok import ngrok`.
4. Add you auth token details using the config command you get from your Ngrok dashboard. Copy the command with '!' before in your code cell.
5. Assign your connection to local variable. Example - `temp_connect = ngrok.connect(5000)` ('5000' is my localhost port I want to take public. In your case it is '8888').
6. To see your assigned public url, call your local variable you've assigned to your connection. `temp_connect`. Url will have domain like '.ngrok-free.app'
7. To disconnect simply write `temp_connect.disconnect(5000)`.

Collectively it'll look like this-
[Ngrok Temp Instance][2]

Hope this helps !
[1]: https://ngrok.com/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6O51.png

Comment: tried this now and it's not working ;(